# Is defaultProps valid in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am following a tutorial and they set a `static object` named `defaultprops` and after setting it `this.props` could be used in the same component, Why is this possible, I mean what's the function of the `static defaultProps` and is it a bulit in function in React.

```
class TestComponent extends Component {
    static defaultprops = {
        food: ["goatmeat", "yam"]
    }

    render() {
        let categories = this.props.defaultprops.food.map(foods => {
            return <option key={foods}>{foods}</option>
        });

        let {test} = this.props;

        return (
            <p>
                {this.props.test}
            </p>
        );
    };
}
```

Comment: It's react magic. Don't think about it too hard

Comment: [typechecking-with-proptypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values)

Comment: also this one may help too. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#defaultprops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default props are nice to not have to specify all of the props when passing them to a component.  Just as the name implies, it allows you to set nice defaults for your props which will be used in the even that overriding values are not passed in.  Please keep in mind that *leaving out* the prop will result in the default value being used, whereas *passing in null* will result in the null value to be used.

More info may be found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#defaultprops).

**Edit**
To answer the questions asked more explicitly:

This is possible because this is how React works.  This is in-built functionality for programmer and logical convenience.

For the `TestComponent` in your example, imagine that it is used in another component.  If you just use `<TestComponent />`, the component will have a `food` value of `["goatmeat","yam"]`.  However,  you may always override this as you wish by passing in a different value for the prop when calling it.  For example, you could use `<TestComponent food={["cheese", "eggs", "cabbage"]}/>`.  This will result in this instance of the component having the `food` value of `["cheese", "eggs", "cabbage"]`.

I think it is also a good point to note that it should be `defaultProps` and not `defaultprops` because I am fairly certain capitalization matters but if anyone would like to correct me I would be happy to redact this point.